# method reverse django error

Tags: python, django, reverse

I'm calling a method using reverse but I have problem argument that I am not able to understand. 
My error :
Reverse for 'shopping.views.payment_confirmation' with arguments '(35,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

My url:

```
url(r'^payment_confirmation/(?P<id>\d+\d{2\})/$', 'payment_confirmation', name='payment_confirmation'),
```

My view:

```
def show(request):
    ...
    ...
    payment.submit(settings.SITE_URL + reverse("shopping.views.payment_confirmation", args=[payment.id]))
```

My model Payment:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    def submit(self, redirect_url):
        '''
            Sends self as a Payment through PagSeguro API.
            Payment instance MUST BE SAVED before calling this method.
        '''

        if not self.id:
            #Temporary to identify which problem caused the crash.
            raise ValidationError

        #creating a reference if its None
        if self.reference is None:
            self.reference = configs.PAGSEGURO_REFERENCE_PREFIX + str(self.id)

        document = Document()
        document.appendChild(self.to_element(document, redirect_url))

        response = document2dict(api.submit_payment(document))

        try:
            self.code = response['checkout']['code']
            self.answered_on = datetime.datetime.now()
            self.save()
        except:
            error_str = ""
            if type(response["errors"]["error"]) != list:
                response["errors"]["error"] = [response["errors"]["error"]]
            for error in response["errors"]["error"]:
                error_payment = ErrorPayment()
                error_payment.code = int(error['code'])
                error_payment.payment = self
                error_payment.save()
                error_str += "[%s: %s]" % (error_payment.code,
                                           error_payment.get_code_display())
            raise Exception(error_str)
```

the error is here payment.submit (settings.SITE_URL + reverse ("shopping.views.payment_confirmation", args = [payment.id]))
I', using this api https://bitbucket.org/leonardosantos/django-pagseguro2/

Answer (score 2):

This line: reverse("shopping.views.payment_confirmation", args=[payment.id]) tells Django to find a url that matches a method called payment_confirmation in the views.py file in the shopping app that will accept a payment ID parameter.

In the error that you shared, the payment.id was 35. The error is saying that either there is no method called payment_confirmation in your shopping.views or the method does not accept a single int as a parameter.

You didn't share a payment_confirmation method in your views file so it seems that that is the issue. You need to add:

```
def payment_confirmation(payment_id):
 #do stuff
```

to your views.

Comment: Hi Jeremy!

I have this method in view and yet the error continues.

Comment: def payment_confirmation(request, id):
    return HttpResponse("aguarde o pagamento, obrigado!")